# Move a work item backwards Salesforce DevOps

Tags: apex, devopscenter

Started using Salesforce Devops to try it out; I'm confused on best practice with work items. The scenario is we have some changes (apex code in this case) promoted along to a pre prod environment. In testing, it was determined we needed to make some changes to the code. What is the best way to go about this in devops? Is it to make a brand new work item and promote it along? Or can the work item be moved back in someway? Sorry for the bit of vagueness, we're experimenting moving from GH actions to this, so need to understand if its worth making the shift. Thanks.